# How to filter by ethernet MAC address

Tags: python, scapy, packet-sniffers

The following code:

```
sniff(filter = "dst aa:bb:cc:dd:ee" )
```

throws an error because `sniff` is expecting an IP, not a MAC.

So how are you supposed to filter by MAC?

Comment: can you use the interface?

Comment: Can you explain a bit deeper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what about specyfing a `lfilter` for `sniff` ?

```
zzz = sniff(lfilter=lambda d: d.src == 'aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff')
```

`dst` and `src` are attributes of sniffed message.

previously i have posted an answer where `stop_filter` was specified. i suppose that it wouldn't work for you, since scapy would stop after receving first packet that match the mac address from `stop_filter`. `lfilter` should do the job.

from `sendrecv.py`:

```
lfilter: python function applied to each packet to determine                   
         if further action may be done                                         
         ex: lfilter = lambda x: x.haslayer(Padding)
```

Comment: I tried your answer with the lfilter in my script and in the interpreter. I pinged from the correct source MAC and it didn't seem to sniff it.

Comment: try pinging another ip address?

Comment: My problem was my MAC had uppercase letters and Scapy delivers lowercase letters. Works beautifully =)

Answer (score 2):

The `filter` parameter needs a BPF filter. The correct syntax is hence `filter="ether dst aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff"`.

This is (much) faster than using a Python function as `lfilter` parameter, as suggested (correctly) by macfij in another answer (plus you don't have to deal with upper/lower-case letters in MAC addresses).