# Filtering packets by src mac in scapy

Tags: python, wifi, scapy

When I filter the packets using this filter in wireshark: 
    wlan.sa == 04.b1.67.14.bd.64
All goes perfect.

However, I'm trying to do it with the following python script using scapy, but it never filter by the source mac:

```
from scapy.all import *
from datetime import datetime
import traceback
# import MySQLdb

def getAverageSSI():
    global ssiFinal
    return ssiFinal

def setParams():
    global window
    global timestamp
    global SSID
    global datetime
    global iterator1
    window = 1
    timestamp = datetime.now()
    SSID='DefaultName'
    iterator1 = 0
    global ssiArray

    ssiArray = []


def myPacketHandler(pkt) :
    global SSID
    global timestamp
    global iterator1
    global ssiArray

    try :

        if pkt.haslayer(Dot11) :

            ssiNew = -(256-ord(pkt.notdecoded[-4:-3]))

            ssiArray.append(ssiNew)

            diffT=(datetime.now()-timestamp).seconds


            if diffT>window:

                print 'With MAC dst = %s with SSI Power= %s' %(pkt.addr1, sum(ssiArray)/len(ssiArray))
                print ssiArray
                ssiArray = []

                timestamp=datetime.now()

    except Exception as e:
        print 'Exception'
        print e
        traceback.print_exc()
        sys.exit(0)


setParams()

try:
    sniff(iface="wlan1", filter="ether src 04:b1:67:14:bd:64", prn = myPacketHandler, store=0)
except Exception as e:
    print e
    print "Sniff AP1 Off"
```

I have also tried to remove the filter in sniff, and put an if like the following:

```
if pkt.addr1 == '04:b1:67:14:bd:64' : # mac xiaomi mi a1

            # SSID = pkt.info;
            ssiNew = -(256-ord(pkt.notdecoded[-4:-3]))

            ssiArray.append(ssiNew)

            diffT=(datetime.now()-timestamp).seconds


            if diffT>window:

                # query = "START TRANSACTION;"
                # queryBack=cur.execute(query)

                # query = "INSERT INTO RSSI VALUES(%d,\"AP1\",%d);"%(iterator1,ssiNew)
                # queryBack = cur.execute(query)

                print 'MAC = %s with SSI Power= %s' %(pkt.addr1, sum(ssiArray)/len(ssiArray))

                ssiArray = []
                # Conexion.commit()

                # iterator1+=1

                timestamp=datetime.now()
```

But it is only filtering by destination mac.

Do you know how to properly filter by mac like in the following wireshark image? (it needs to be exactly the same behaviour than in  the wireshark filter):

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24386000/how-to-filter-by-ethernet-mac-address

Comment: @jfleach That solution doesnt work, i already tried it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second method should be working well, if you used `addr2` instead of `addr1`

[image: Dot11 FCS packet]

Here is how it works in 802.11 (yes it’s really messy)
[image: How 802.11 addresses work]

Also, you should update to the github scapy version, which has support for RSSI directly (so you don’t have to parse notdecoded)

[image: RadioTap example]

See https://github.com/secdev/scapy/archive/master.zip

Comment: You are right. I was confusing it with addr1. Do you know were can I get documentation about what is addr1, addr2, ...? It's confusing for me.